# How to junit return type of a method in spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-mvc-test

I am doing junit on my Spring MVC controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HashMap<String, String> handleRequest() {
    HashMap<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String name = "Hello World";
    model.put("greeting", name);

    return model;
}
```

And below is my junit for the above method -

```
public class ControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new Controller()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test01_Index() {

    try {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/index")).andExpect(status().isOk());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Above junit works fine..

But my question is how do I junit the return type of `handleRequest` which is returning a `HashMap` with key and value pair.. How do I verify that it is returning `Hello World`? Is there any method to do that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [at the examples in the Spring reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server) referring to using MockMvc to test server-side code. Assuming you are returning a JSON response:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/index"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.greeting").value("Hello World"));
```

By the way - never catch and swallow an exception in a `@Test` method, unless you want to ignore that exception and prevent it from failing the test. If the compiler is complaining that your test method called a method that throws an exception and you didn't handle it, simply change your method signature to `throws Exception`.

Comment: Thanks.. that works.. One more thing suppose my `handleRequest` method takes a string parameter, then how would I pass that from my junit test?

Comment: @AKIWEB that is covered in the linked document, look in the "Performing Requests" section