# java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set while junit Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test-mvc

I am using JUnit to test my Spring MVC controller. Below is my method which returns a `index.jsp` page and shows `Hello World` on the screen -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HashMap<String, String> handleRequest() {
    HashMap<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String name = "Hello World";
    model.put("greeting", name);

    return model;
}
```

And below is my JUnit test for the above method:

```
public class ControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new Controller()).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test01_Index() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(get("/index")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.greeting").value("Hello World"));

    }
}
```

Above junit was working fine when I debugged it but when I ran the junit as `run as junit`, it gave me this error -

```
MockMvc : Circular view path [view]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/view] again
```

So to fix that I followed this [tutorial](http://myshittycode.com/2014/01/17/mockmvc-circular-view-path-view-would-dispatch-back-to-the-current-handler-url-view-again/) and after that I am getting this exception -

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:39)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers$1.match(ContentResultMatchers.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
    at com.ebay.personalization.bullseye.zookeeper.test.ZookeeperControllerTest.test01_Index(ZookeeperControllerTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:602)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

What am I doing wrong here? On the .jsp page it shows `Hello World`..

I am following up on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182167/how-to-junit-return-type-of-a-method-in-spring-mvc-controller/22182342?noredirect=1#comment33670375_22182342)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I see a couple of issues with the request mapped method:

Ideally, you should have a `@ResponseBody` annotation on your method, to indicate that the returned content is to be streamed out:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public HashMap<String, String> handleRequest() {
    HashMap<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String name = "Hello World";
    model.put("greeting", name);

    return model;
}
```

Now with this done, your test can look like this:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/index").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith("application/json"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.greeting").value("Hello World"));
```

In your case, what is happening is Spring is trying to figure out the view name and is getting the view name as `index`, which is again the controller path, thus the circular view path error that you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

You should also check your request mappings:

Does get("/...") match @RequestMapping ?

If the handleRequest is never called, you will get the same error `Content type not set`.

Comment: You are  absolutely correct! I just changed the mapping in the code , missed to do the same in my Junit! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the mocked services in your controller return something.

when(myservice.getResult()).thenReturn(someObject);

Without some form of result Spring cannot determine the content type.