# java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set - Spring Controller Junit Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockmvc

I am trying to do some unit testing on my controllers.  No matter what I do all controller tests return

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set
```

I am testing that the methods return json and xml data.

Here is an example of the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mypath")

public class MyController {

   @Autowired
   MyService myService;

   @RequestMapping(value="/schema", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<MyObject> getSchema(HttpServletRequest request) {

       return new ResponseEntity<MyObject>(new MyObject(), HttpStatus.OK);

   }

}
```

The unit test is set up like this:

```
public class ControllerTest() { 

private static final String path = "/mypath/schema";
private static final String jsonPath = "$.myObject.val";
private static final String defaultVal = "HELLO";

MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
MyController controller;

@Mock
MyService myService;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(),
                        new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter()).build();


    when(myService.getInfo(any(String.class))).thenReturn(information);
    when(myService.getInfo(any(String.class), any(Date.class))).thenReturn(informationOld);

}

@Test
public void pathReturnsJsonData() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(get(path).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath(jsonPath).value(defaultVal));
}
```

}

I am using:
Spring 4.0.2
Junit 4.11
Gradle 1.12

I have seen the SO question [Similiar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183178/java-lang-assertionerror-content-type-not-set-while-junit-spring-mvc-controller) but no matter what combination of contentType and expect in my unit test I get the same result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your solution depends on what kinds of annotation you want to use in your project.

- You can add `@ResponseBody` to your getSchema method in Controller
- Or, maybe adding `produces` attribute in your `@RequestMapping` can solve it too.

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value="/schema", 
        method = RequestMethod.GET, 
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} )
  ```
- Final choice, add headers to your `ResponseEntity` (which is one of the main objective of using this class)

  ```
  //...
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  return new ResponseEntity<MyObject>(new MyObject(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
  ```

Edit : I've just seen you want Json AND Xml Data, so the better choice would be the `produces` attribute:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schema", 
      method = RequestMethod.GET, 
      produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE} )
```

Comment: This helped, Thank You.  I acutally was in the process of separating my controller into two controllers.  One with the RestController annotation which adds ResponseBody to all methods and a second standard spring controller.  I was referencing the wrong controller so the mockMvc.perform was returning null and the first expect was failing which is the content check.  Dumb mistake but thought I'd mention it in case anyone else does the same thing.

Comment: produces = {} did not work for me. I am using Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE. Solved with response.setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);

Comment: @söber, that's strange. Do you have the `accept` header of your request well set ?

Comment: In another deployed app I am seeing Request headers: Accept:application/pdf and
Response headers: Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8. In MockMVC test request has Accept=[application/pdf] and response has header Content type = null.

Comment: The question was about json and xml, not pdf :) `produces` is a way to use different serialization (json, xml, ...) for the same data controller. There is no automatic converter for pdf, as far as I know.

Comment: I fixed a this error by making sure controller method doesn't return null.

Comment: Above answer by @JR Utily is correct; however in my case I was using the RestController and the API was returning content type header correctly.
However, I was facing above issue because I was using org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
I replaced it with org.junit.Test and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
method = RequestMethod.GET
value = "/schema")
```

And `<mvc:annotation-driven />`in your xml config or `@EnableWebMvc`