# java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set even after setting content type as json/application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

This question has been asked before and I have tried their solution but that doesn't work for me, I am using `MockMvc` to unit test content type of my rest call.
I am getting this exception:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set

While I'm setting it in my search method using `produces` attribute.

This is the method where I am initializing the mocks:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(restController, "luceneSearchEnabled", true);
    mockMvc = standaloneSetup(restController).build();
}
```

This is my test method:

```
@Test
public void pmmSearchContentTypeTest() throws Exception { 
    mockMvc
          .perform(get("/api/v1/pmm").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
          .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
          .andReturn();
}
```

This is my search method where I am setting content type:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/" + REST_API_VERSION + "/" + ONE_INTERFACE, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces ={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public String pmmSearch() { ... }
```

I don't know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error and found that , the mock service for this controller method returns null. change mock service method to return values for any() input and test this to get rid of this error.

```
when(service.method(any())).thenReturn(someElement);
```

someElement was null earlier causing this error case

Comment: In my test, I found that the passed input didn't have any value. And so, it was giving this error:`java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself

Instead of using the mock object of retcontroller here

```
mockMvc = standaloneSetup(restController).build();
```

I had to use a real object

```
mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new RestController()).build();
```

and in order to avoid spring validation error I had to use complete path here

```
mockMvc
.perform(get("/api/v1/pmm/search{}").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response returns null, you can get that error, as it says @stuti-verma.
It happened to me right now.

The case: In my test, I was sending a json to the controller, but the object that I used to generate the mocked response didn't have the equals/hashCode implemented. So, it will never match with the received json.

```
@RequestBody anObject

mock.theMethod(anObject).thenReturn(theResponse)
```

anObject must have equals/hashCode to be able to be compared

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to set the content type returned by the request in the ResponseEntity itself:

```
PaymentResponse paymentResponse = makePaymentService.makePayment(paymentRequest);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
return new ResponseEntity<>(paymentResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
```

see [java.lang.AssertionError: Content Type Not Set - Spring Controller JUnit Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166167/java-lang-assertionerror-content-type-not-set-spring-controller-junit-tests/24173196)